# what happen when accessibility service is enabled but the permission on app is disabled at runtime, what happen to the accessibility service events

Tags: android, accessibility, android-permissions, accessibilityservice

what happen when the accessibility service is enabled but the permission on app is disabled at runtime then what happen to the accessibility service events in android. I am not able to understand that when certain app has disabled the permission at runtime of certain events then will the accessibility service will fire the events. Will it works as usual or it will require that particular permission to fire the event. This I am doing in Android.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the permissions related to events etc, then As per my experience, and  experimentation, it is not possible for a normal user to revoke the permissions at the runtime.
Only an advance user will be able to do that and that too via adb shell and root commands.
Once it is done, your accessibility service will just crash and won't work at all.
I have tested this with Pixel 3 and android 9 Pie.
Editting the service metadata upon runtime is very complicated for an average user.
Please let me know if you have other queries.